# Data not getting stored in Firestore when the firestore package from rnfirebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I used the @react-native-firebase/firestore package for my React native app. I have installed my firebase/app as well and followed all the installation steps in the firebase web page. But I am not able to store data into my firestore. Here's the code I have used.

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export const storeData = async (userDetails) => {
  let userName = userDetails.userName;
  let storeSuccess = await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc('123')
    .set({
      username: userDetails.userName,
      userselfie: userDetails.userSelfie,
      LP: userDetails.LPImage,
      bill: userDetails.BillImage,
      customercontact: userDetails.customerContact,
      date: userDetails.date,
      time: userDetails.time,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((error) => {
      error.message && alert(error.message);
      console.log(
        'Something went wrong while adding user data to firestore: ',
        error,
      );
      return 'error';
    });
  return storeSuccess;
};
```

I have done everything and the above function is even getting called but I get a `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` as a response from the firestore function.

Comment: {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null} means that you are logging an unresolved promise !

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await` along with `Promise.then()` may be causing this unexpected behavior. In order to fix your function, delete the `async/await` and instead keep the `then()` notation as follows:

```
export const storeData = (userDetails) => {
let userName = userDetails.userName; 
let storeSuccess = firestore()
.collection('Users')
    .doc('123')
    .set({
      username: userDetails.userName,
      userselfie: userDetails.userSelfie,
      LP: userDetails.LPImage,
      bill: userDetails.BillImage,
      customercontact: userDetails.customerContact,
      date: userDetails.date,
      time: userDetails.time,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((error) => {
      error.message && alert(error.message);
      console.log(
        'Something went wrong while adding user data to firestore: ',
        error,
      );
      return 'error';
    });
  return storeSuccess;
};
```